# How they are able to interact with virtual world without having to wear or hold any VR device in Mixed Reality?

Tags: interaction-design, interface, virtual-reality

I watched this video about an [Interactive Mixed Reality game show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-84piSTkyY&feature=youtu.be) and I would like to try out mixed reality in Unreal. I noticed they don't use any VR headset or using any handheld device to interact inside the virtual world.

I was wondering if they are using **mocap** or already setting up all the equipment inside the studio that receive inputs like a normal input device or there is another tricks that I've been missing out.

I've seen many mixed reality games that need VR device and stuff and the ones in that video is very interesting for me that I would like to try out in the future.

Any ideas on how they are able to interact with virtual world without having to wear or hold any VR device?

Sorry for the long post.

Comment: I suggest you contact the makers of the video and ask them directly. It's impossible for anyone other than the video's technical staff to know for sure how they achieved what you see on the screen. It is my experience that video production companies are friendly and willing to share technical information.

Comment: Questions asking '*how / why did {company x} do {thing*' are ones we can only speculate on, not explicitly answer. If you want to know how / why they were designed that way you'd have to contact the company themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at just the trailer, this looks to be simply a case of buzzword bandwagoning.

The players themselves don't seem to do much, if anything, with mixed reality devices. They're using physical machines similar to those in 90's tv game shows. The only difference is that in the 90's they used styrofoam sets, and this show uses a large greenscreen.

There seem to be two types of games in the trailer. Realworld games that use set props as interface (e.g. ratcheting something or having to catch a certain amount of balls) which are just a physical game with a greenscreen, and perhaps a scorecounter or timer. And secondly, arcade-style games that involve shooting or driving, which are shot in such a way that there could be a display off-screen foe the viewers.

So while it might be realtime composites for viewers, it's not mixed reality for the players, in the sense that they only see a part of both mixed realities and not the endresult.

But 'mixed reality' sounds fancy, and it obviously grabbee your attention, so good job from the marketing department..